# Why does Binary encoding give me a whole column of 0s?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, encoding

I have an issue with an entire column returning 0s even for another dataset with 100+ unique values.

Can I ask why this is the case (here it is column "automobile_0")?
And can I just drop it off safely?

```py
data = {'automobile':['car','car','car','car','scooter','scooter','bike','bike','bike']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

import category_encoders as ce    
encoder = ce.BinaryEncoder(cols=['automobile'])
df = encoder.fit_transform(df)
df
output[0]
automobile_0    automobile_1    automobile_2
0   0   0   1
1   0   0   1
2   0   0   1
3   0   0   1
4   0   1   0
5   0   1   0
6   0   1   1
7   0   1   1
8   0   1   1
```

[image: picture of the output]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNtsS.png)

Comment: Please: copy the output in the question, and do not link to figures. Easier for us to copy in an answer, it is easier to check the problem (most of us will not open external links, and most will just check next question if they find an incomplete question). -- BTW: you should also select the tag better (we filter question by tag). You are using `pandas` so use also that tag, and also a unknown to me `ce` module (add a tag, or specify in the question)

Comment: I think you should read the documentation. Maybe "binary encoding" needs few extra values (0,0,0, and an other) to describe no-data and error. I think you can drop it, because it is redundant information (in your dataset, which I assume was already cleaned, which often it is not the case)

Answer (score 1):

Try out pandas get_dummies instead. Think that's what you're looking for.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'automobile':['car','car','car','car','scooter','scooter','bike','bike','bike']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pd.get_dummies(df)
```

output:

[image]

If you want to you can just rename the columns after that.

Comment: Hello! Im using Binary encoding as i want to reduce 100 unique values to simply just... 7 columns of data... which one hot (get dummies) can't do for me.

Even with 100 unique values, i still get a whole column of 0s and im afraid it might affect how the machine views the column and be unable to use it to help classify my label

Comment: Could you explain your problem a bit more in detail? What are you trying to achieve? Which model are you using?

Comment: I was using a few models, random forest was one of them. 

The issue was that my column had too many unique values (high cardinality) and to one hot them would be an overkill... and hence chose binary encoding instead.

But i ran into the while column of 0s issue and thought maybe someone has the asnwers as i did a few google searches and could not find the answer i needed. Thank you though!